# $L^2$ Convergence of series of normally distributed independent random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(W_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a iid sequence of $N(0,1)$ random variables and

$$X(f):=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}c_k(f)W_k, \ f \in L^2[-\pi, \pi]$$

with

$$c_k(f):=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)e^{-ikx}, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I'm trying to prove that this series converges in $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and looking for hints.
Is there any 'clever' way or trick to show this? I don't really know how to start.

I also want to determine $E[X(f)]$, $V[X(f)]$ and $Cov[X(f),X(g)]$ for $f,g \in L^2[-\pi, \pi]$

$E[X(f)]=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}c_k(f)E[W_k]=0$.

$V[X(f)]=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}(c_k(f))^2V[W_k]=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}(c_k(f))^2$

$Cov[X(f),X(g)]$=?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Hilbert space $L^{2}(P)$ the family $(W_k)$ is orthonormal. Hence $\sum a_kW_k$ converge sin $L^{2}(P)$  iff $\sum |a_k|^{2} <\infty$. In our case $\sum |c_f(k)|^{2} <\infty$ because $f \in L^{2} ([-\pi,\pi])$.

Comment: Can you explain why $(W_k)$ is orthonormal in $L^2(P)$?

Comment: $EW_kW_l=(EW_k) E(W_l)=0$ if $k\neq l$ by independence. This is orthogonality. $EW_k^{2}$ is the variance of $W_k$ which is $1$. Hence $\{W_k\}$ is orthonormal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also need to determine $E[X(f)], V[X(f)]$ and $Cov[X(f),X(g)]$. I added it avove. Should I open a new question?

Comment: For covariance use the fact that EW_kW_j=0 for distinct k and j.

Comment: For covariance I ended up with $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}c_k(f)c_k(g)$. Is that correct?

Comment: @user651597 Yes, it is correct. You have to observe one thing here. $X(f)$ is not an ordinary real valued random variable. It is a 'complex valued' random variable. May be this is what is causing some confusion in your mind. I am assuming that covariance is defined by $EX(f)X(g)-EX(f)EX(g)$.